# How would you filter a swift dictionary on its value type?

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift4

I am looking for an elegant (functional) way to filter a dictionary based on the pair value type, when all values are not of the same type. I.e. a way to go from `[AnyHashable : Any]` to `[AnyHashable : T]` ?

Using `flatMap` gives you an array of tuples that could be reduced:

```
var result = dictionary.flatMap({ pair in
    pair as? (AnyHashable, T)
}).reduce([AnyHashable : T]()) { dict, tuple in
    var dict = dict
    dict[tuple.0] = tuple.1
    return dict
}
```

But I am not satisfied with this implementation... are you?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Swift 4 `reduce(into:)` method which the partial result it is already mutable:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func flatMapValues<T>(into type: T.Type) -> [Key: T] {
        return reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.key] = $1.value as? T }
    }
}
```

---

```
let dict: [AnyHashable: Any] = ["key1": 1, "key2": 2, 3: "Three", Date(): "Just a String", "key5": 5]

let integersDictionary = dict.flatMapValues(into: Int.self) // ["key2": 2, "key5": 5, "key1": 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of `reduce` for this, `Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:)` seems better suited:

```
let dict: [AnyHashable: Any] = [
  1: 1,
  2: "foo",
  "3": 3,
  4: 5.0,
  true: "17"
]

func filterByType<T>(_ dict: [AnyHashable: Any]) -> [AnyHashable: T] {
   return Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: dict.flatMap { ($0,$1) as? (AnyHashable, T) })
}

let strValues: [AnyHashable: String] = filterByType(dict)
```